# Referring to variables by column names

Tags: r

I have a matrix, say `X`, whose columns I need to use in R. I named each column using the `colnames` command. However, when I type the name of a column, nothing comes up. To illustrate, I used a code like the one below:

```
colnames(X) <- c("column1","column2")
```

When I type `X`, `column1` and `column2` appear at the top of the columns. However, when I type `column1` or `column2`, they cannot be found.

Does anyone know what needs to be done?

Comment: That's not what he's asking

Comment: Sorry, I misread your intent.

Answer (score 8):

This is a fairly basic part of `R`, when you have a column name, row name, list element name, etc., you have to tell `R` the object to look inside first.

In your case, you would have to do:

```
X[,"column1"]
```

to get `column1`.

A better option for you is a `data.frame`:

```
X <- data.frame(Column1 = c(....), Column2 = c(....))
X$Column1 #Returns "Column1"
```

In both cases you're now correctly telling R to look for something named `column1` inside of `X`.

As Matthew states below, if you need to call `column` without referring to `X`, you can use `attach(X)` first. Most people tend to avoid this, as it creates a new copy of the element - and that can get messy if you end up changing `column1`

Comment: If it is a data.frame, `attach` is what the questioner may want.

Answer (score 3):

Here's such a matrix:

```
X <- matrix(1:6, ncol=2)

colnames(X) <- c("column1","column2")
X
     column1 column2
[1,]       1       4
[2,]       2       5
[3,]       3       6

attach(as.data.frame(X))
column1
[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew. This works, but is not what I am looking for I am afraid. I need to call them by their column names only. By that, I mean when I type column1 (or whatever I call it), the number in that column should appear.

Comment: @Günal Edited.  Perhaps you need `attach`, but that does not work for a `matrix`.

Comment: Unfortunately, as Matthew said, attach does not work for a matrix. What else can be done guys? Thoughts please

Comment: @Günal Use a `data.frame` or an `environment`.

Comment: @Günal make your matrix a data.frame!