# reference to dataframe headers in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called Out and column headers with Speed, Accelertion, Distance etc. I have created objects with reference to their position in the Out dataframe.I want to loop through the dataframe and then go to the function 'behaviour' (below also). The problem is, the function doesn't recognise the column headers/referece as I have it below i.e. 
**'if (max(Speed >= 2.45))**

Could anyone give me the correct format? Many thanks.

```
behavModel <- list() # list to store model results
for (m in seq(from = 1, to = nrow(Out), by = 32)){
 Distance <- (Out[m, 5])
 Speed <- (Out[m, 6])
 behaviour <- behaviour(Speed, Acceleration, Distance, Absolute_Heading, Relative_Heading, Movement, Changes)
}


behaviour <- function(Speed, Acceleration, Distance, Absolute_Heading, Relative_Heading, Movement, Changes)
{

# walking
if (max(Speed >= 2.45)) behaviour <- "walking"

return (behaviour)

}
```

This is what Out looks like. I just want to loop through and fermorm function like 
if the maximum speed in a 'segment' of 32 instances i >= 2.45 mph then class as walking for example. Sorry about the alignment!

```
      latitude_position_1 longtude_position_1 latitude_position_2 longtude_position_2          Distance Speed Acceleration Absolute_Heading        Relative_Heading   Movement Changes Transition
1      91.1227553646932   -6.23305421507455    91.1227518740347       -6.2330489790868 0.400505694328303  0.03        0.012 236.306305752159       -236.306305752159       left       0       ****
2      91.1227518740347    -6.2330489790868    91.1227483833762     -6.23304374309904 0.400505709727528 0.155        0.038 236.306307393042   -1.64088351084501e-06    forward       1       ****
3      91.1227483833762   -6.23304374309904    91.1227483833762     -6.23303850711129 0.333912980750125 0.155       -0.038 270.000002484092      -33.6936950910497    forward       0       ****
4      91.1227483833762   -6.23303850711129    91.1227483833762    -6.23304374309904 0.333912980750125  0.09        0.012 89.9999975159082       180.000004968184 non-moving       1 Transition
5      91.1227483833762   -6.23304374309904    91.1227483833762    -6.2330489790868 0.333912980750125 0.275        0.062 89.9999975159082                       0 non-moving       0       ****
6      91.1227483833762    -6.2330489790868    91.1227483833762     -6.2330559604038 0.445217307591311 0.275       -0.062 89.9999966878713   8.28036945677013e-07 non-moving       0       ****
7      91.1227483833762    -6.2330559604038    91.1227431473884   -6.23304548842829 0.745675662288711  0.12            0 243.431811475523     -153.431814787652       left       1       ****
8      91.1227431473884   -6.23304548842829    91.1227448927177   -6.23304374309904 0.156892934292016 0.275        0.062 315.003927795227     -71.5721163197041 non-moving       1       ****
9      91.1227448927177   -6.23304374309904    91.1227536193639   -6.23306468705007  1.44555679702924  0.31       -0.048 67.3773348964212      247.626592898806      right       1       ****
10     91.1227536193639   -6.23306468705007    91.1227536193639   -6.23306643237932 0.111304317308227 0.155       -0.014 89.9999991716402     -22.6226642752191    forward       1       ****
11     91.1227536193639   -6.23306643237932    91.1227588553517   -6.23306643237932 0.331723741058604 0.155        0.014                0      89.9999991716402 non-moving       1       ****
12     91.1227588553517   -6.23306643237932    91.1227623460102   -6.23306643237932  0.22114916222707  0.19            0                0                        0 non-moving       0       ****
```

Comment: Would the solution provided here help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025953/referring-to-variables-by-column-names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (max(Speed >= 2.45)) behaviour <- "walking"
```

I think you should correct the parentheses to make it work properly:

```
if (max(Speed) >= 2.45) behaviour <- "walking"
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I now get a new problem, that 'max not meaningful for factors' hmmm......

Comment: Could you provide code to create a sample Out object producing this error?